# How do I sample single (random) rows that can be grouped by a column's values?

Tags: r, random, grouping, subset

Here is a sample of the data

```
p <- structure(list(name = structure(1:5, .Label = c("Alice", "Bob",
"Charlie", "Dennis", "Earl"), class = "factor"), cohort = structure(c(3L,
3L, 2L, 2L, 1L), .Label = c("X", "Y", "Z"), class = "factor"),
    group = structure(c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L), .Label = c("A",
    "B"), class = "factor"), var = c(1L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 4L)), .Names = c("name",
"cohort", "group", "var"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA,
-5L))
```

that looks like

```
     name cohort group var
1   Alice      Z     A   1
2     Bob      Z     A   2
3 Charlie      Y     B   1
4  Dennis      Y     B   3
5    Earl      X     A   4
```

and I need something like the following, based on the `cohort` column. I need to sample one row in each `cohort` (possibly randomly) so that I don't have multiple people belonging to the same `cohort`.

```
     name cohort group var
2     Bob      Z     A   2
3 Charlie      Y     B   1
5    Earl      X     A   4
```

I can `group_by` cohort, but then I'm not sure how to proceed to create a new data frame with only the rows that I need.

Comment: Another base r : `idx = sapply(split(rownames(p), p$cohort), sample, 1) ; p[idx, ]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can group by `cohort` and pipe it to `sample_n` where 1 indicates that you want one sample per group

```
library(dplyr)

p %>% group_by(cohort) %>% sample_n(1)

Source: local data frame [3 x 4]
Groups: cohort [3]

name cohort  group   var
(fctr) (fctr) (fctr) (int)
1   Earl      X      A     4
2 Dennis      Y      B     3
3  Alice      Z      A     1
```

Second run:

```
 name cohort  group   var
 (fctr) (fctr) (fctr) (int)
 1    Earl      X      A     4
 2 Charlie      Y      B     1
 3     Bob      Z      A     2
```

Comment: Hey, thanks, that works perfectly. Is there a way of making this repeatable? That is, on that RNG is `sample_n` is based, do I can seed it?

Comment: @Morpheu5 you can use `set.seed(1)` (or any other number) every time before you repeat the sample.

Answer (score 3):

You can try to use `aggregate` with `sample` to choose which value to keep, first, changing `name` and `group` columns from factor to character:

```
p$name <- as.character(p$name) ; p$group <- as.character(p$group)
aggregate(.~cohort, data=p, FUN=function(x) x[sample(seq_along(x), 1)])
#  cohort   name group var
#1      X   Earl     A   4
#2      Y Dennis     B   1
#3      Z    Bob     A   2
```

Answer (score 1):

"Possibly random but not necessarily" happens to be, what SQL gives:

```
library(sqldf)
sqldf("SELECT * FROM p GROUP BY cohort")
```

in this case I get

```
> sqldf("SELECT * FROM p GROUP BY cohort")
    name cohort group var
1   Earl      X     A   4
2 Dennis      Y     B   3
3    Bob      Z     A   2
```

Comment: this doesnt seem to be random `replicate(10, sqldf("SELECT * FROM p GROUP BY cohort"), simplify = FALSE)`

Comment: It happens not to be random in this implementation but SQL does not specify, so we don't know what happens in the next version. The original poster did not specify, if random was wanted or just a possibility and I put the first line in my answer as a warning. If the original poster really wants it to be random, which he did not specify, this answer is not for him. Otherwise I think this is short and elegant and fast.

Comment: `group by` would give the last observation from the group.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the sampling library:

```
library(sampling)
n <- length(unique(p$cohort)) 
s <- strata(p, 'cohort', rep(1, n), method = 'srswor')
p$id <- row.names(p)
p[p$id %in% s$ID_unit, ]
```